# How to fix "ld: library not found for -lxxx " on my Mac when "pip3 install mysqlclient"?

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I was going to use Django to develop my personal blog. I encountered this problem when configuring the environment:

```
~ » pip3 install mysqlclient  hwangziqi@huangziqideMBP
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-install-bbsgdat8/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-install-bbsgdat8/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-install-bbsgdat8/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 53, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-install-bbsgdat8/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        raise Exception("Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?")
    Exception: Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?
```

So, i tried https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 .

```
$ mysql_config
Usage: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/include ]
        --cxxflags       [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/include ]
        --include        [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/include]
        --libs           [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/lib -l ]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/lib -l ]
        --plugindir      [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/lib/plugin]
        --socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [6.1.10]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/include]
                pkglibdir     [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/lib]
                plugindir     [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/lib/plugin]

`--libs` and `--libs_r` should have ` -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto`, but it only have `-l`.
```

and now:

```
» pip3 install mysqlclient  hwangziqi@huangziqideMBP
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-install-85s5jozc/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-record-x9p5inkf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-install-85s5jozc/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-record-x9p5inkf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/09/s28t32055hl9z2mcffwjhq040000gn/T/pip-install-85s5jozc/mysqlclient/
```

i tried to reinstall openssl and mysql-connector-c by brew, but it was useless. My English is poor, I hope you can understand it. Thx so mush.

Comment: you may need `openssl-dev` with C/C++ files `*.h` (headers)

Comment: Do you have any lessons in this field?I don't quite understand the solution you're talking about.

Comment: your message shows that it uses C compiler `gcc` to compile mysql library which will be used with Python module. C has two types of file - `.c` with code and `.h` with headers which are used during compilation to get information about code in already compiled files. It seems MySQL want to work with module `ssl` so it needs `.h` files from `ssl` to compile MySQL's code which will use  `ssl` function. File `OpenSSL` has only precompiled code - without .c and .h files. `OpenSSL-dev`(and any packed with `-dev`) has `.h` which MySQL may need to correctly compile its code.

Comment: I don't havy any lesson for this. I know this because I learnt C/C++ long time ago - before I even learnt Python.